# How can I add a line per grouping in grafana without hardcoding multiple queries?

Tags: grafana

I have data that can be aggregated by the company that produced the data item. There are around 96 such companies. As such I don't want to use 96 queries, as this seems inefficient.

How can I get grafana to do this with time series data please so I can get all the lines on the same graph?

CAVEAT: I get that 96 data streams is a lot on one graph. However I'm interested in boundary breaches and outliers which don't occur very often per supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana creates multiple lines if you have 3 variables called time, metric and value. Metric has to be a string and in this case I suppose it is the company id. If it is an integer id then you need to cast it to string. Also the query type needs to be time series.

For me, this works:

```sql
SELECT
  date AS 'time',
  cast(runDate AS char) as 'metric',
  value/1000 as 'value'
FROM forecast
WHERE $__timeFilter(runDate)
ORDER BY date
```